# Leetcode: Flatten binary tree to linked list C#

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, linked-list, tree, depth-first-search

https://leetcode.com/problems/flatten-binary-tree-to-linked-list/

Please comment on performance

> Given a binary tree, flatten it to a linked list in-place.
>
> For example, given the following tree:
>
> ```
>     1
>    / \
>   2   5
>  / \   \
> 3   4   6
> ```
>
> The flattened tree should look like:
>
> ```
> 1
>  \
>   2
>    \
>     3
>      \
>       4
>        \
>         5
>          \
>           6
> ```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace LinkedListQuestions
{
    [TestClass]
    public class FlattenBinaryTree2LinkedList
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void FlattenBinaryTree2LinkedListTest()
        {
            TreeNode root = new TreeNode(1);
            root.left = new TreeNode(2);
            root.right = new TreeNode(5);
            root.left.left = new TreeNode(3);
            root.left.right = new TreeNode(4);
            root.right.right = new TreeNode(6);
            Flatten(root);
            Assert.AreEqual(1, root.data);
            Assert.AreEqual(2, root.right.data);
            Assert.AreEqual(3, root.right.right.data);
            Assert.AreEqual(4, root.right.right.right.data);
            Assert.AreEqual(5, root.right.right.right.right.data);
            Assert.AreEqual(6, root.right.right.right.right.right.data);

        }
        public void Flatten(TreeNode root)
        {
            if (root == null || (root.left == null && root.right == null))
            {
                return;
            }
            Stack<TreeNode> stack = new Stack<TreeNode>();
            var head = root;
            stack.Push(root);
            while (stack.Count > 0)
            {
                var curr = stack.Pop();
                if (curr != root) // in the first iteration, we don't want to move the head to the next item
                {
                    head.right = curr;
                    head = curr;
                }
                if (curr.right != null)
                {
                    stack.Push(curr.right);
                    curr.right = null;
                }
                if (curr.left != null)
                {
                    stack.Push(curr.left);
                    curr.left = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the moment you do a new Stack(), you violate the restriction to doing it "in-place". You have to move the nodes around in the same tree, without using a helper

Comment: @fernando yes I think you are right. I will try another solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first condition is a bit conservative:

> ```
> if (root == null || (root.left == null && root.right == null))
> ```

Just `if (root == null)` would be enough, the rest of the implementation naturally handles the cases of `root.left == null && root.right == null`.

---

Evaluating `curr != root` for every node, when it's only useful for the first node is a bit ugly.
You could get rid of that by not adding `root` itself on the stack, but its children. (In the right order, and when not null.)

---

`head` is a misleading name for a variable that traverses all the nodes,
especially since the end result is effectively a linked list,
where "head" usually means the first element.
I'd rename this to `node`.

---

All the `curr.right = null;` can be safely dropped,
because `curr.right` will either get overwritten with the intended value,
or it's `null` to begin with (in the very last node).

---

An \$O(n)\$ solution exists without using a stack:

- When left is null and right is not, advance over right
- When right is null and left is not, move left to right and advance over right
- When both not null of `node`, then:

  - traverse through all the right descendants of `node.left`, and append at the end `node.right`
  - move `node.left` to `node.right` and advance over it

Answer (score 1):

Your solution use a single loop to iterate through all elements
so the complexity is O(N), where N is the number of elements.

The performance can be improved a little by removing the first if statement and inserting left before right in the stack

Comment: If I put left before right. The result will be wrong

Comment: Yes, Right before Left is the right order. As left will be processed before Right